# Itext myImage.Alignment = Image.TEXTWRAP | Image.ALIGN_RIGHT; VB Equivalent?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, itext

Hopefully a really easy question!

I am using ITextSharp and am trying to set the alignment of an image.

In C# (as per all the examples) it is:

```
myImage.Alignment = Image.TEXTWRAP | Image.ALIGN_RIGHT;
```

I cannot work out the equivalent of the "|" in VB.

Bex

Comment: [C# to VB Converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) in case you're interested.

Comment: Thanks.. I shall try that in future! I sthought it was something specific Itext though for some reason! :)

Comment: @Brad Christie - "|" is just an OR.  "^" is the exclusive OR in C#.

Comment: @RQDQ: You're right, was a Freudian slip. I take back my comment, and my apologies for confusion--been a long week. :grin:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myImage.Alignment = Image.TEXTWRAP Or Image.ALIGN_RIGHT;
```

**EDIT:** It's important to understand what's happening under the covers (and the difference between bitwise and logical operators).

I don't have the actual binary values of the flags in your sample, but let's say that TEXTWRAP is binary 0001 and ALIGN_RIGHT is binary 0010.  When you bitwise or the two:

**Bitwise Or**

```
0010
0001
----
0011
```

You actually do an or on each bit.  In this case, that gives us a mask that has the bits for both TEXTWRAP and ALIGN_RIGHT set.

**Bitwise And**

It sounds like you're getting hung up on the English description of what you're trying to do... You want TEXTWRAP and ALIGN_RIGHT.  While this makes sense from a verbal description, if you tried to perform a bitwise and of these two values:

```
0010
0001
----
0000
```

Note that neither of the flags that you're interested are set.

Comment: I thought it was or, but it doesn't seem correct in the context as I think it's trying to say Align right and Wrap Text. Shall try it.

Comment: If you want to "And" then you'd use & in C# or And in VB.

Comment: "Or" in VB is the the same as "|" in C#.  "And" in VB is the same as "&" in C#.

Comment: @Bex - I added some additional detail / explanation.

Answer (score 1):

VB uses `Or` rather than `|` for the bitwise `OR` operator, if I recall correctly.

So, this *should* work:

```
myImage.Alignment = Image.TEXTWRAP Or Image.ALIGN_RIGHT
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bitwise C# operator.  Just change it to "Or" in VB.